# How to Increase timeout in Angular 4 http post call (observables)

Tags: angular, http-post, angular2-observables

I am new to Angular 4. I have developed an application which aims at uploading files. I am not supposed to use any file upload libraries ,hence I'm relying on java script file upload and preparing a base 64 string to post to API. I could able to upload files and hit the API but I'm failing in uploading Large files.My client requirement is to upload files till 50 MB of size. I have increased the timeout to 2400000 (40 mins) but still my api call is a failure. Client is ok with wait time of 3 hrs but I cant increase the timeout .Please help.Below are my code and screen shots of api call response:

```
return this._http.post(this._edaUrl, jsonData, {headers: header})
  .timeoutWith(2400000, Observable.throw(new Error('Timeout')))
  .map(res => {
     return res;
   })._catch(this.handleError);
```

[image: API Response]

Comment: I can upload files of 100MB in less than a minute. Are you sure your problem is the timeout ? What is the error you get ?

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I can successfullt uplaod a file of size 9mb,but post that Im getting the issue.Below is the error ::POST http://localhost:8080/api net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

ErrorMessage:Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error

Comment: Well, this means you don't answer anything from your API. You're supposed to return something, even if it's an empty content, but this isn't Angular related. What is your backend, nodeJS ? This also explains why you're waiting so long : Angular waits for a response, but it never comes.

Comment: Mulsoft is my api. Also I can get proper response for file of lesser sizes.What I suspect is zone is discarding the request as per the error message .

Comment: Your error message is pretty clear : ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. It means you don't have a response. If the file is too big (and I highly doubt 50MB is too big), then another message will pop. Here, the problem comes from your backend. The http call is done, but has failed, because it lacks a response. Maybe your backend can't process files this big ? See the logs of it, and don't hesitate to post them here too

Comment: Many thanks for pointing it out. I will ask my API team to post logs meanwhile can you please let me know do we have any limitations for timeout. I mean can Angular wait for infinite period to get the response ,say if response takes 1 hr of time because my back-end runs lot of rules

Comment: This isn't an Angular issue (again), it's the **keep-alive** header that handles this. You can [find more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Keep-Alive)